# Expected a type - Operator function

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

It worked but now it does not work anymore and I don't know why.

I have this code :

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
  std::string operator"" _quoted(const char* text, std::size_t len) {
        return "\"" + std::string(text, len) + "\"";
    }
```

And during the compilation, I have this error :

```
error: expected a type
    std::string operator"" _quoted(const char* text, std::size_t len) {
                        ^
```

and this is the "" which is highlighted in red.

I really don't understand what happened and what is the reason why it is not working anymore.

could you please help me ?

thank

Comment: Did you miss `-std=c++11` ?

Comment: Still compiling with C++11?

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing me out this. Indeed, the option in my CMakeList has been removed. So I added again the -std=c++11 compile option and now everything work.
thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Thank to @Pow and @Gill Bates, I was able to solve the problem. I don't know why ont my CMakeList the c++ 11 option has been removed.

So I added this line and everything work now.

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++)
```

Thank !